# Integer min/max in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I see in the [CUDA Math API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1gef4476ab1d2818b60097fdc4064a395a) documentation that there are functions for single and double precision min/max operations (e.g. `fminf()`). I assume these are highly optimized, etc. There don't seem to be functions like these for integers. Is this true? Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are min/max device functions for integers, but they are all called with an overloaded `max()`.  Look in device_functions.hpp:

```
__DEVICE_FUNCTIONS_STATIC_DECL__ int max(int x, int y)
{
  return __nv_max(x, y);
}

__DEVICE_FUNCTIONS_STATIC_DECL__ unsigned int umax(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  return __nv_umax(x, y);
}

__DEVICE_FUNCTIONS_STATIC_DECL__ long long llmax(long long x, long long y)
{
  return __nv_llmax(x, y);
}

__DEVICE_FUNCTIONS_STATIC_DECL__ unsigned long long ullmax(unsigned long long x,
                                                 unsigned long long y)
{
  return __nv_ullmax(x, y);
}
```

They're not listed in the Integer Intinsics section because in math_functions.hpp the `max` function is overloaded to call these functions for you. The `__nv*` functions are documented in device_function_decls.hpp.

Comment: For what it is worth these intrinsics map straight to hardware instructions. If you disassemble your binary with `cuobjdump --dump-sass`, you will find instructions like `IMNMX` = "integer minimum or maximum" (a predicate selects whether this performs `min()` or `max()`)

Comment: For me the code with `__nv_min` doesn't compile. Which compute capability does it require?

Comment: @SergeRogatch You just use `max` and overload resolution will handle it.  Either you are not compiling the file with nvcc, or you forgot to include cuda_runtime.h. Be sure you have no macros for max though.  I think math_functions.hpp has the overloads

Comment: @chappjc, with just `min` it compiles, it is definitely `nvcc`, as there is a lot of other CUDA code in the file. `cuda_runtime.h` is included. But `__nv_min` doesn't compile (it says that the function is undefined).

Comment: @SergeRogatch It's working then.  Direct use is not intended.