# How to fix error calling a __host__ function("std::max<double> ") is not allowed in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, caffe

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
template <typename Dtype>
    __global__ void R_D_CUT(const int n, Dtype* r, Dtype* d
        , Dtype cur_r_max, Dtype cur_r_min, Dtype cur_d_max, Dtype cur_d_min) {
        CUDA_KERNEL_LOOP(index, n) {
            r[index] = __min(cur_r_max, __max(r[index], cur_r_min));
            d[index] = __min(cur_d_max, __max(d[index], cur_d_min));
        }
    }
```

In above code, it can work well in Window. However, it does not work in Ubuntu due to `__min` and `__max` function. To fix it by replace `__min` to `std::min<Dtype>` and  `max` to `std::max<Dtype>`:

```
template <typename Dtype>
    __global__ void R_D_CUT(const int n, Dtype* r, Dtype* d
        , Dtype cur_r_max, Dtype cur_r_min, Dtype cur_d_max, Dtype cur_d_min) {
        CUDA_KERNEL_LOOP(index, n) {

            r[index] = std::min<Dtype>(cur_r_max, std::max<Dtype>(r[index], cur_r_min));
            d[index] = std::min<Dtype>(cur_d_max, std::max<Dtype>(d[index], cur_d_min));
        }
    }
```

However, when I recompile, I got the error

```
_layer.cu(7): error: calling a __host__ function("std::min<float> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<float> ") is not allowed

_layer.cu(7): error: calling a __host__ function("std::max<float> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<float> ") is not allowed

_layer_layer.cu(8): error: calling a __host__ function("std::min<float> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<float> ") is not allowed

_layer_layer.cu(8): error: calling a __host__ function("std::max<float> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<float> ") is not allowed

_layer_layer.cu(7): error: calling a __host__ function("std::min<double> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<double> ") is not allowed

_layer_layer.cu(7): error: calling a __host__ function("std::max<double> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<double> ") is not allowed

_layer_layer.cu(8): error: calling a __host__ function("std::min<double> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<double> ") is not allowed

_layer_layer.cu(8): error: calling a __host__ function("std::max<double> ") from a __global__ function("caffe::R_D_CUT<double> ") is not allowed
```

Could you help me to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, functionality associated with `std::` is not available in CUDA device code (`__global__` or `__device__` functions).

Instead, for many math functions,  NVIDIA provides a [CUDA math library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html#axzz4oho32nbR).

For this case, as @njuffa points out, CUDA provides templated/overloaded versions of `min` and `max`.  So you should just be able to use `min()` or `max()` in device code, assuming the type usage corresponds to one of the available templated/overloaded types.  Also, you should:

```
#include <math.h>
```

Here is a simple worked example showing usage of `min()` for both `float` and `double` type:

```
$ cat t381.cu
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
__global__ void mymin(T d1, T d2){

  printf("min is :%f\n", min(d1,d2));
}


int main(){

  mymin<<<1,1>>>(1.0, 2.0);
  mymin<<<1,1>>>(3.0f, 4.0f);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o t381 t381.cu
$ ./t381
min is :1.000000
min is :3.000000
$
```

Note that the available overloaded options even [include some integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978155/integer-min-max-in-cuda)

Comment: I am fairly certain CUDA has templated versions of `min()` and `max()`. Or at least overloaded ones.

Comment: Thanks. It worked well. I just have one more question. In case of non CPU code (.CPP file), I also need to use max and min function as above, but when I used your way, it has error `_layer.cpp:205:25: note: ‘max’ declared here, later in the translation unit`. Do we need any change in .cpp version

Comment: I would probably need to see a specific example.  You might want to ask a new question, I think this now has nothing to do with CUDA.  Are you declaring your own definition of `max`?  It's not clear to me that what you are showing is actually an error anyway.

Comment: Please check it in here https://gist.github.com/John1231983/dd06a20a003f26fb30560ece71225b68#file-batch_renorm_layer-cpp-L203 . I must used std::max to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @RobertCrovella's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45488348/1593077): If you want something which behaves more like `std::max`, you can use this  templated wrapper over CUDA's math library:

```
#define __df__ __device__ __forceinline__
template <typename T> __df__ T maximum(T x, T y);
template <> __df__ int                 maximum<int               >(int x, int y)                               { return max(x,y);    }
template <> __df__ unsigned int        maximum<unsigned          >(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)             { return umax(x,y);   }
template <> __df__ long                maximum<long              >(long x, long y)                             { return llmax(x,y);  }
template <> __df__ unsigned long       maximum<unsigned long     >(unsigned long x, unsigned long y)           { return ullmax(x,y); }
template <> __df__ long long           maximum<long long         >(long long x, long long y)                   { return llmax(x,y);  }
template <> __df__ unsigned long long  maximum<unsigned long long>(unsigned long long x, unsigned long long y) { return ullmax(x,y); }
template <> __df__ float               maximum<float             >(float x, float y)                           { return fmaxf(x,y);  }
template <> __df__ double              maximum<double            >(double x, double y)                         { return fmax(x,y);   }
#undef __df__
```

<sub>(see [here](https://github.com/eyalroz/libgiddy/blob/master/src/cuda/on_device/builtins.cuh) for a more complete set of these wrappers.)</sub>